# Trying to auto increment a formula

Tags: excel

Hi I have this formula for concatenation and it works correctly other than having to increment each time it is being pasted into the next cell.

Here is the formula:

`=CONCATENATE(INDIRECT("AG"&"$"&(ROW()  + 1))," | ", INDIRECT("AG"&"$"&(ROW() + 2)))`

I just need for it to go up each time it is being pasted. I think I'm on the right track but any help would be appreciated.

Also this is what i want the code to increment:

`=CONCATENATE(INDIRECT("AG"&"$"&(ROW()  + 1))," | ", INDIRECT("AG"&"$"&(ROW() + 2)))`
`=CONCATENATE(INDIRECT("AG"&"$"&(ROW()  + 2))," | ", INDIRECT("AG"&"$"&(ROW() + 3)))`
... etc

Comment: Are you copying the formula across or down? ROW() or COLUMN() should be enough as an incrementor?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure which row the formula will start on, but assuming it starts on Row 10, this will work.

`=CONCATENATE(INDIRECT("AG"&"$"&(ROW()  + (Row()-9)))," | ", INDIRECT("AG"&"$"&(ROW() +(Row()-8))))`

You can adjust for whatever row you need as the start row.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the solution:

I added a helper column (AK) from the numbers that i would need up to. Then used that in for formula as follows:

=CONCATENATE(INDIRECT("AG"&"$"&(ROW()  + AK1))," | ", INDIRECT("AG"&"$"&(ROW() + AK2)))

Thanks for everyones help